# readFully(byte[] b, int off, int len) and EOFException

Tags: java, tcp, io

I'm encountering this exception a lot in a piece of code I have, and it's happening when I call readFully. I don't understand how it can happen though, because readFully is supposed to block until len bytes are available. If it knows that that many bytes are available, how can it then later meet an EOF?

And how can I get around this issue? (I'm reading the first 3 bytes to get the length (TL part of TLV) and then encountering the issue sporadically when reading the V).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> throws: EOFException - if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.

So this behavior is expected if the length you send is not correct (i.e. is larger than the actual length), or if the sender closes the stream before having written all the bytes.

Comment: So, if the person on the other end tells me to expect 50 more bytes, but only actually sends 20, then I get this error? Can I use the EOFException to just read as much as possible?

Comment: You got it. This is a bug at the sending side, which should be fixed. You should handle the exception in case this bug is not fixed or comes back again, by displaying an error message for example. I wouldn't try to do as if it was normal to receive a number of bytes different from what has been specified in the beginning of the message.